# create n*n DataFrame using custom function

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have column like this shown below:

```
  Data
0    A
1   Av
2  Zcef
```

I want desire output with using some function like

```
def len_mul(a,b):
    return len(a) * len(b)
```

This function can be replace,

```
Data  A  Av  Zcef            
A     1   2    4
Av    2   4    8
Zcef   4  8    16
```

I am able to do this using for loop, But I don't want to use for loop.
I am trying using `pd.crosstab`, but I am stuck at `aggfunc`.

**`len_mul`** function is important as this is example function for simplicity.

Comment: Do you mind to show us your loop so we can better understand the logic you are using? Are you using the  name len()? Why you have `Zce` and `Zcef`? From where it comes the last one?

Comment: sorry typing mistake.. i corrected it

Comment: Please have a look at timing in my updated answer.

Comment: @user32185 Thank you for your updates, I wanted something  where i can replace len_mul function with my real function.

Comment: I got it. I wanted just to stress the point that vectorial solutions are faster ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your custom function:

```
def len_mul(a,b):
    return len(a) * len(b)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Data'], df['Data']])
df_out = pd.Series(idx.map(lambda x: len_mul(*x)), idx).unstack()
df_out
```

Output:

```
     A  Av  Zcef
A     1   2     4
Av    2   4     8
Zcef  4   8    16
```

This was from @piRSquared [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45441253/6361531)

---

You can use `np.outer` with pd.DataFrame constructor:

```
lens = df['Data'].str.len()
pd.DataFrame(np.outer(lens,lens), index = df['Data'], columns=df['Data'])
```

Output:

```
Data  A  Av  Zcef
Data             
A     1   2     4
Av    2   4     8
Zcef  4   8    16
```

Comment: Actually i want using some custom functions so i can replace that custom function

Comment: Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this as an elaborated comment. I think it mostly depends on your `len_mul` function. If you want to do exactly the same as in your question you could use a little of linear algebra. In particular the fact that multipl a matrix nxq with a matrix qxm you obtain a matrix nxm.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Data":["A", "Av", "Zcef"]})
# this is the len of every entries
v = df["Data"].str.len().values
# this reshape as a (3,1) matrix
v.reshape((-1,1))
# this reshape as a (1,3) matrix
v.reshape((1,-1))
#
arr = df["Data"].values
# this is the matrix multiplication
m = v.reshape((-1,1)).dot(v.reshape((1,-1)))
# your expected output
df_out = pd.DataFrame(m,
                   columns=arr,
                   index=arr)
```

**Update**

I agree that Scott Boston solution is good for the general case of a custom function. But I think you should look for a possible way to translate your function to something you could do using Linear Algebra.

Here some timing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
alph = list(string.ascii_letters)

n = 10000
data = ["".join(np.random.choice(alph,
                                 np.random.randint(1,10))) 
        for i in range(n)]
data = sorted(list(set(data)))
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data":data})


def len_mul(a,b):
    return len(a) * len(b)
```

## Scott Boston 1st solution

```
%%time
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Data'], df['Data']])
df_out1 = pd.Series(idx.map(lambda x: len_mul(*x)), idx).unstack()

CPU times: user 1min 32s, sys: 10.3 s, total: 1min 43s
Wall time: 1min 43s
```

## Scott Boston 2nd solution

```
%%time
lens = df['Data'].str.len()
arr = df['Data'].values
df_out2 = pd.DataFrame(np.outer(lens,lens),
                       index=arr,
                       columns=arr)

CPU times: user 99.7 ms, sys: 232 ms, total: 332 ms
Wall time: 331 ms
```

## Vectorial solution

```
%%time
v = df["Data"].str.len().values
arr = df["Data"].values
m = v.reshape((-1,1)).dot(v.reshape((1,-1)))
df_out3 = pd.DataFrame(m,
                       columns=arr,
                       index=arr)

CPU times: user 477 ms, sys: 188 ms, total: 666 ms
Wall time: 666 ms
```

## Conclusions:

The clear winner is Scott Boston 2nd solution with my 2x slower. The 1st solution is, respectively,   311x and 154x slower.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be building the array with list comprehension instead of a loop. 
That way, you can easily create a dataframe with it afterwards.

Example usage:

```
import pandas as pd

array = ['A','B','C']

def function (X):

    return X**2

L = [[function(X) for X in pd.np.arange(3)] for Y in pd.np.arange(3)]
L
>>> [[0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4]]

pd.DataFrame(L, columns=array, index=array)
```

[image]

some text on it:  https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

hope it helps!

Comment: there are still 2 loops.